# On the relationship between limit, infimum and supremum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Given $\lbrace{ a_n \rbrace} \rightarrow a$, ie., the sequence $a_n$ converges in the limit to $a$, we have to prove the following relationship

$$\inf_n a_n \le a \le \sup_n a_n$$

**Proof attempt.** Since $\lbrace{ a_n \rbrace} \rightarrow a$, so for all $\varepsilon > 0$, $\lvert a_n - a \rvert < \varepsilon$.

Therefore, $-\varepsilon < a_n - a < \varepsilon \Rightarrow a -\varepsilon < a_n < a + \varepsilon$.

Now we prove the left half of the inequality in question (the right half is similar). Suppose for contradiction that $a < \inf_n a_n = \alpha$; then because $\alpha$ is the infimum, for $\varepsilon > 0$ we have,

$$a < \alpha \le a_n < a + \varepsilon < \alpha + \varepsilon $$

So this is the part I can't get past; I can't think of a way the above relationship can be contradictory. One line of reasoning is that for arbitrary choices of $\varepsilon$, we can construct any number of cases, such as with $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, so that $\alpha \le a + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \le a_n < a + \varepsilon < \ldots$ which means I can always have a larger $\alpha$.

This type of reasoning, however, seems a little too convoluted to be useful. If I am on the correct track, how should I formalise this argument? Alternatively, if I am incorrect, where am I going wrong?

Comment: "Since $\lbrace{ a_n \rbrace} \rightarrow a$, so for all $\varepsilon > 0$, $\lvert a_n - a \rvert < \varepsilon$."—This isn't correct as stated. For all $\varepsilon$, there is an $N$ such that $\lvert a_n - a \rvert < \varepsilon$ whenever $n\ge N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few general comments about your answer specifically.

1. As was mentioned in a comment above, your statement of the definition of the limit of a sequence is incorrect.
2. $\alpha$ is not the supremum. It is the infimum, by your definition. I think that's just an honest mistake on your part.
3. Now, you've shown that:

$$a < \alpha \leq a_n < a+\epsilon < \alpha+\epsilon$$

But where does that bring you, though? It doesn't seem to establish much of anything, really. At least, I don't see a way to get past that problem.

---

Now, I'll give you my argument for this. Define the following set:

$$E = \{a_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$

Since $\{a_n\}$ converges, it is bounded. So, $E \neq \varnothing$ and is bounded. Hence, $sup(E)$ exists and $inf(E)$ exists. I will show that:

$$a \leq sup(E)$$

Suppose that $a > sup(E)$. Then, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that:

$$a-\epsilon > sup(E)$$

So, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$\forall n \geq N: a_n \in (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$$

This implies that:

$$\forall n \geq N: a_n > a-\epsilon > sup(E)$$

which is a contradiction. So, it follows that $a \leq sup(E)$. A similar argument can be made for the infimum.

Comment: This makes sense. Just one question -- when you state "there exists an $\epsilon >0$ [s.t.] $a-\epsilon >\sup(E)$", is the "choice" of $\epsilon$ still arbitrary or is this only true for specific $\epsilon$. 

My understanding here is that the statement holds because $a >\sup(E)$ so $a$ can not be the supremum, which means such an $\epsilon$ exists, and this should generally be true.

Comment: Well, I do have several choices for what $\epsilon$ could be. In particular, I know that there has to exist a rational number in the interval $(sup(E),a)$ and an irrational number in the same interval. These will, of course, be different and there's a way of constructing $\epsilon$ for them.

However, the thing we have to remember is that this is all that's needed, really. We just needed this particular $\epsilon$, whatever it is, in order to use the reasoning that came after that.